# Creating unique time measurement ID for each user based on date of measurement (varying per user)

Tags: r

I am having a problem with my analyses in R that I am hoping you guys can help me with. So I have a dataset with multiple daily measurements per participant (DiaryEating), all participants have a unique ID (UserID), and all measurements are timestamped with the date (DateVariable). However, these measurements instances differ for participants (i.e.  some got measured on the 1st, others on the 3rd of the month). For my analysis, instead of the DateVariable, I need a Time variable that indicates whether this is the 1st, 2nd or 3rd measurement PER participant.

This sounds very simple, but has proven very difficult to me (Yes, I do indeed suck very hard at this).
Code looks something like:
UserID (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
DateVariable( 2018/10/30, 2018/10/31, 2018/11/01, 2018/10/30, 2018/10/31, 2018/11/03, 2018/10/30, 2018/10/31, 2018/11/02, 2018/11/04)
DiaryEating (3,3,4,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5) 
TimeMeas(WHAT I WANT TO CREATE WOULD BE): 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::group_by` as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  mutate(Time = row_number())
```